# Android scroll position requires screen touch to update (jsfiddle included)

Tags: android, jquery, scroll, touch

I have a simple div with the overflow set to auto, and a label that shows the scrollLeft() position of the div. it works on IOS, the number moves up and down as your scroll. On Android (tablet) though it fails to update the value of the scrollLeft() function until after an additional screen touch is recorded? Any Ideas? Thanks

Look at this example at the link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yatescr/37Axm/) then try it from an android tablet, the position will not update until the screen is touched after you slide the div.

Thanks.  example div

```
<div id="divSchedule" class="overlay">
<div data-role="content" id="ScheduleContent">
    <label id="label1">0</label>
    <br />
    <label id="label2">No Event</label>
    <br />
    <div id="xory" class="tsInnerXorY">
        <table id="tblSchedule" class="tsScheduleTable">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:Blue">111111111</td>
                <td style="background-color:red">111111111</td>
                <td style="background-color:Blue">111111111</td>
                <td style="background-color:red">111111111</td>
                <td style="background-color:Blue">111111111</td>
                <td style="background-color:red">111111111</td>
                <td style="background-color:Blue">111111111</td>
                <td style="background-color:red">111111111</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```